# Python, A string split into many pieces. How many pieces are in there?

Tags: python, split

I split a very long string separated by semicolons and I want to know how many split items are there?

I recall that this has to do with lists and there is a method in python that tells you how many are in that list. I couldn't remember the method for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could get the length of the list of items after splitting:

```
len(my_long_string.split(';'))
```

Alternatively, count the number of semicolons and add one:

```
my_long_string.count(';') + 1
```

The latter is probably faster if you don't need to know *what* the items are, but only *how many* items there are.

[`len`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) is a function that returns the number of items in a list. Strings have a method called [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) that splits a string on a delimeter. They also have a method called [`count`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) that counts the number of non-overlapping instances of a substring.

Comment: Neat approach with use of `.count()`

Answer (score 2):

```
len(line.split(';'))
```

will tell you how many strings there are separated by semicolons in your line.

`line` is your data, [split(';')](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.rsplit) will split the line using the semicolon as delimter and create a list of strings, and [len()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len) will tell you how many items there are in the list.